# Unable to get loop working correctly

Tags: java

I am trying to make a calculator with a certain input that is entered like + 5 5 or / 10 2. When I compile and run it I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
>   at calc.main(calc.java:11)

My Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class calc {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        String calc;
        double num1;
        double calcdu = 0.0;
        double num2;
        while ( true ) {
            calc = input.next();
            num1 = input.nextDouble();
            num2 = input.nextDouble();

            if (calc.equals("+"))
            { 
                    calcdu= num1 + num2;
                    System.out.printf("%.2e %s %.2e %c %.2e\n", num1, "+", num2, '=', calcdu);
            }       

            if (calc.equals("/"))
            {   
                calcdu=num1/num2;
                System.out.printf("%.2e %s %.2e %c %.2e\n", num1, "/", num2, '=', calcdu);
            }

            if (calc.equals("-"))
            {   
                    calcdu=num1-num2;
                    System.out.printf("%.2e %s %.2e %c %.2e\n", num1, "-", num2, '=', calcdu);
            }       
            if (calc.equals("*"))
            {   
                    calcdu=num1*num2;
                    System.out.printf("%.2e %s %.2e %c %.2e\n", num1, "*", num2, '=', calcdu);
            }
            if (calc.equals("%"))
            {   
                    calcdu=num1%num2;
                    System.out.printf("%.2e %s %.2e %c %.2e\n", num1, "%", num2, '=', calcdu);
            }

}}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "submit it"?
Do you mean you run the program using java command?

Comment: @Iyen Haha, just typing that, *exactly*. :-) As a guess, however you're running it has stdin tied to your machine's equivalent of /dev/null, so the first attempt to scan anything results in end-of-file.

Comment: How is the loop supposed to end, and why are the variables defined outside the loop?

Comment: Works for me. Program starts, waits for input, I type `+ 5 5<enter>` and it prints `5.00e+00 + 5.00e+00 = 1.00e+01` (weird format, man), I then type `/ 10 2<enter>` and it prints `1.00e+01 / 2.00e+00 = 5.00e+00`, I then killed it, because there's no way to end it normally. So, how are **you** running it?

Comment: Thank you I got it working!

Answer (score 1):

Your calling `next()` on `scanner` without checking with `hasNext()`

```
while(input.hasNext())
{
 num1 = Double.parseDouble(input.nextDouble());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(input.nextDouble());

......//further code
```

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs when there are no more tokens in `scanner`, and you try to get next, without checking. See [NoSuchElementException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) from Java docs.
In your case, as `Ramanlfc` mentioned, you are calling `Next()` on scanner without checking with if `next` even exists. You can use `hasNext()` to check if next exists.

Answer (score 0):

The NoSuchElementException occurs when a class tries to get an element or token and there aren't any there. For example, if the Scanner class is trying to get the next element from standard input and there's nothing there (empty or null). This can happen if the user doesn't enter anything or the program terminates prematurely.

You can avoid this by first checking that the user has entered something before moving on with your program.

For the Scanner class, this can be done using the hasNext() method or some variation of it.

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29)

As an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String operator = "";
    if (input.hasNext()) {  // Check that Scanner has input
        operator = input.next();
    }
    while (true) {
        if (operator.isEmpty()) { // No value entered, program can't continue
            System.out.println("No value entered, program will now exit.");
            break;
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because there is no tokens in the Scanner for the function to obtain. You should check that there are tokens left in the Scanner with the `Scanner.hasNext()` function.

There is also an easier way to make calculations based on user input, using a JavaScript engine, like so:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    String operator = kbd.next();
    double number1 = kbd.nextDouble();
    double number2 = kbd.nextDouble();

    System.out.println(engine.eval(number1 + operator + number2));
}
```

For this to work you will need to add `import javax.script.*;` to the top of your java file, along with the other imports.